# Knative dispatch event messages over HTTPS

Tags: https, knative, knative-eventing

I have a Knative trigger configured. Events should be handled by a service running over HTTPS.

```yaml
apiVersion: eventing.knative.dev/v1
kind: Trigger
metadata:
  name: my-trigger
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  broker: my-broker
  filter:
    attributes:
      type: dev.knative.sources.ping
  subscriber:
    ref:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
      namespace: event-handler-ns
      name: event-handler-service
    uri: /handle/event
---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: event-handler-service
  namespace: event-handler-ns
spec:
  selector:
    app: event-handler
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
```

If I look at the logs of the broker filter, I can see the events are sent via HTTP. And I can't find any documentation how to POST them via HTTPS.
The [only documentation I can find](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/using-a-tls-cert/) is to configure the knative services to run on HTTPS (not my custom service that does the event handling).

```
{
  "level": "error",
  "ts": "2022-10-12T08:05:13.202Z",
  "logger": "mt_broker_filter",
  "caller": "filter/filter_handler.go:216",
  "msg": "failed to send event",
  "commit": "e825770",
  "error": "failed to dispatch message: Post \"http://event-handler-service.event-handler-ns.svc.cluster.local/handle/event\": EOF",
  "stacktrace": "knative.dev/eventing/pkg/broker/filter.(*Handler).send\n\tknative.dev/eventing/pkg/broker/filter/filter_handler.go:216\nknative.dev/eventing/pkg/broker/filter.(*Handler).ServeHTTP\n\tknative.dev/eventing/pkg/broker/filter/filter_handler.go:209\ngo.opencensus.io/plugin/ochttp.(*Handler).ServeHTTP\n\tgo.opencensus.io@v0.23.0/plugin/ochttp/server.go:92\nknative.dev/pkg/network/handlers.(*Drainer).ServeHTTP\n\tknative.dev/pkg@v0.0.0-20220524202603-19adf798efb8/network/handlers/drain.go:110\nnet/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP\n\tnet/http/server.go:2879\nnet/http.(*conn).serve\n\tnet/http/server.go:1930"
}
```

Is it possible to specify the protocol in the trigger for the subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uri` can be an absolute URL with a non-empty scheme and non-empty host that points to the target (or a relative URI). From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/knative.dev/pkg/apis/duck/v1#Destination)

So you should be able to specify the protocol when using only the uri:

```
subscriber:
  uri: https://event-handler-service.event-handler-ns/handle/event
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the `URI` can be a `HTTPS` endpoint, but the actual implementation depends on the `dispatcher` code in the `broker`. Generally it does work by providing the custom TLS certificates, if any, similar to [this](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/tag-resolution/) approach for `tag` resolution.

Which `broker` are you using?

Comment: Currently using the default broker (mt-channel-broker): https://knative.dev/docs/install/yaml-install/eventing/eventing-installation-files/
My project is still in development phase, knative setup is not production ready yet.

Haven't tried providing certificates yet, because the other solution works for me.